# How to get network days by subtracting from current date and older date on Jasper soft studio?

Tags: postgresql, jasper-reports

I need to find net workdays by subtracting from older date from today ?
Ex:Today Date is 7/14/2020 and older date is some 7/14/2019.
Expected result = 365.

Answer (score 0):

The expression is `extract(days from now() - <older date column>)`.

My recommendation is to have the database server perform this calculation for you by adding the expression to the `select` list in your query.  If you prefer to do this with scripting after Jaspersoft has retrieved the data, then I cannot help you there.